# Please tell me why this Whatsapp template is rejected by Whatsapp to use

Tags: templates, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have submitted the following template for approval many times through woztell and got rejected. Apparently, the reason stated by Whatsapp - "Invalid_Format"

I need to know exactly what are the invalid formats and mistakes that i have done, and how can I rectify these mistakes.

```
<Header:>
*Thank you for filling up the Growth and Development form.*


<Body:>
*Your responses indicate that your child may require pediatric intervention. Please ensure that you show this message to Doctor {{6}} as soon as possible, and get the right advice for your child.*

*Growth and Development Red Flags for Patient {{7}}*
 
1. {{1}}
2. {{2}}
3. {{3}}
4. {{4}}
5. {{5}}

<Footer:>
*Important Message for the Doctor:* The form responses by the patient indicate {{8}} Red flags. Only a maximum of 5 are displayed in this message. The patient has received an email with the list of red flags, kindly ask the patient to share the email with you.
```

Please specify the mistakes that I have done and also suggest me some corrections.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of issues in your template, you have to read about the message [template restrictions and reasons for rejection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/message-templates/guidelines), The below are problems in your template that I know,

- It can't allow using `*` in the header and footer part
- It can't allow any variable in the footer, and you have added {{8}}
- Maximum length of text in the footer is 60 characters
- Too many parameters in the body as per the static content, try to reduce variables..

Answer (score -1):

An empiric observation on the *"too many parameters in the body as per the static content"* as stated by @turivishal.

I can't find any information about this in the docs, but the messages are actually rejected if you don't observe this. So I tried to get what the minimum ratio is and it seems that your message should have at least three times plus one words (including variables) than variables. So if you have one variable you should have at least four words (3 * 1 + 1 = 4), if you have two, at least seven words and so on.